# Exclude folders when publishing

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

It is possible to exclude folders from my publish process when deploying my ASP.NET Core application?

Specifically, the `bootstrap/js` files. These files very rarely change but have made my publish process take forever. I'd like to just be able to exclude them until I know that they have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [`exclude specific files from deployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment#excluding-specific-files-and-folders), you  could follow below steps:

- **`In the Solution Explorer window, right-click the file, and then click Properties`**.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

- **`In the Properties window, in the Build Action row, select None`**

See the screenshot below:

[image]

> ***`Note:`*** Once you implement above changes your selected file will  be excluded from the deployment. You can also do that using `XML command` on your  `project csproj` file. You can have a look on
> [official guideline for further details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment#excluding-specific-files-and-folders).

Comment: The wpp method is what I'm going to go with, there are just too many files to select in all the bootstrap folders.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in Visual Studio select the files you want to exclude, right-click -> properties then the properties window will be opened, in the Build Action choose None.